# How to use Parse Password Reset in JAVA APP

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Using Andriod Studio JAVA and Parse, I am trying to create a Password Reset option. However, I am lost and searched the net but nothing seems to work.

I found a code that I implemented, but not sure what else it needs to work. What do I need to add to make this send an email with the reset link.

I have done the server side to enable email verification and password reset. Any help is appreciated.

```
                        currentUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground(email, new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password rest email has been sent to your inbox", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //ParseTaskUtils.wait(currentUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground());

                            }else if(e.getCode()== com.parse.ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: `I found a code that I implemented, but not sure what else it needs to work` this is why you're struggling. it doesn't help to just find code and then you don't understand what it does or why it does it

Comment: You are right but Parse have no proper documentation and I do understand what it does. Anyhow it works now. thanks.